# ST_ClosestPoint usage in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, spatialite, nearest-neighbor, knn

I try to use `ST_ClosestPoint` function to find the closest point to find the `MultiLineString` layer. My line layer `(Reach)` has 42 attributes and point layer `(Stations)` has 7 attributes. My code is:

```
select
  AsWKT(
    ST_ClosestPoint(
      geomfromgpb(geometry),
      geomfromgpb(geom)
    )
  )
from Stations, Reach
```

*I wrote `geometry` and `geom` for Stations and Reach respectively. They hold geometry with these column names.

It returns me:

```
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9616693.712029119 4307906.197583989)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9667592.713239145 4291816.543706047)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9661404.384824551 4276655.139090295)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9616539.003818756 4267372.646468406)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9590857.440898195 4260256.068791624)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9694202.525421893 4322448.76935828)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
('POINT(9645005.314525882 4320592.270833903)',)
```

Every 7 coordinates show the points in Stations layer respectively. But it should return 42 coordinates totally, because every line has one closest point. However it returns like 7*42 coordinates and every 7 coordinates are same.

I find the function here:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html#p13

And here is my canvas:
[image]

*I manually try to show the point to give clear vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that gives to me the nearest point to the defined line geometry:

```
select r.fid, s.fid, 
  min(
    ST_Distance(
      ST_ClosestPoint(
        geomfromgpb(r.geom),
        geomfromgpb(s.geometry)
      ), 
      geomfromgpb(s.geometry)
    )
  ) as dist
from Stations as s, Reach as r
group by r.fid
```

It gives point id, line id and distance between them respectively. Reach is `line` layer. Station is `point` layer.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [docs](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html), `ST_ClosestPoint(geom1, geom2)`

> Returns the Point on geom1 that is closest to geom2.

so if `geom1` is a *Line* and `geom2` a *Point*, it will return the exact point **on the *Line*** that is closest to the *Point*. Your query above, if `geometry` and `geom` are correctly refered to `Stations` and `Reach` respectively, actually finds the closest point **on each *Point*** for each *MultiLine*...which doesn´t really make sense.
However, I assume you want to find the nearest *Point* in `Stations` to each *MultiLine* in `Reach` (so that each *MultiLine* will be be assigned one of the seven *Points*)?
This is usually refered to as *[K Nearest Neighbor (KNN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)* search...and, unfortunately, is not implemented efficiently in *SpatiaLite* with Version < 4.4.0 (which comes shipped with QGIS 3.0). You will need to do a full `CROSS JOIN` and find the minimum `ST_Distance` between each *MultiLine* and all *Point*s in `Stations`(don´t forget to fill in the `<uid>` column names):

```
    SELECT ln.<uid>,
           pt.<uid> AS closest_point,
           MIN(ST_Distance(pt.geometry, ln.geometry)) AS distance,
           ln.geometry
    FROM Reach AS ln
      CROSS JOIN Stations AS pt
    GROUP BY ln.<uid>
```

This will return the *uid* of the closest point (as *closest_point*) for each *MultiLine*, together with the line *uid*, the distance between *MultiLine* and closest *Point*, and the *MultiLine* geometry.

Hope that helps? Not 100% sure if that is what you want...

Comment: specially thank you for your response.  However your answer give me always same point. I put my answer below and they have same vision.

Comment: @MustafaUçar Well, I´m pretty sure it does the same thing as your answer, except for the (in this case) unnecessary `ST_ClosestPoint` generation (adressing performance on large tables)...anyways, glad you got it to work!